# How should i separate branches for live project in git

Tags: git, version-control

Initially i was in a team where we have one project and all other have separate bracnhes. I didn't knew much git but picked up in small time just doing basic things.

Now all other members have moved and i am fully responsible for the poject. Now the project is live and i ahve to work on its ANother release version.

Currently the default branch is for production and i have my other branch caalled `Johk` where i used to do some stuff.

Now am not sure what is best practices and how can i divide the branches do i need to make 4 branches

```
Johnk
default
Developmenet
Release1
```

or i need to make separate `Prod` branch

I am confused. Please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

With Git, you can do whatever you want.

If your default branch is `production` and you're comfortable with that, that's fine; leave it.  You can merge any other branch into `production` when you want to deploy.  With this scheme, I would call the main development branch `master`, and make feature branches off of `master`.

If I were setting it up from scratch, I would instead use `master` as the production branch, and make a branch called either `develop` or `next` that was the main development branch.  Both of those are widely used.

You might look at some formally-defined Git workflows:

- Atlassian's [Feature Branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch) (pretty easy to understand)
- [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) (I don't like this one; too damn complicated!)
- [GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) (*muuch* better)

There are others.  But mostly you just do what works for you.  Good luck!